# Given a list of categorical features, how can I calculate odds ratios for all possible combinations of those features?

Tags: r

I have a dataset of categorical features. I want to calculate the odds ratio (or 0 if the odds ratio is not significant) for all possible combinations of these categorical features.

This is my function to calculate the odds ratio or alternatively to return 0:

```
oddsratio = function(feature1,feature2) {
    OR = odds.ratio(feature1,feature2)
    if (OR[,4] < 0.05) {
        return(OR[,1])
    }
    else {
        return(0)
    }
}
```

This is my code to create all combinations of the features:

```
features = c('elderly','female','race','stroke','copd','asthma','htn','pad','dyslipidemia','icd',
        'af','thyroid','dm','fracture','smoker_ever','ckd','cad','obesity')

all = combn(features,2)
```

Here's my loop:

```
loop = function(data,features) {
    for (i in 1:ncol(all)) {
        one = all[1,i]
        two = all[2,i]
        dataone = data[[one]]
        datatwo = data[[two]]
        oddsratio(dataone,datatwo)
    }
}
```

I'm receiving an error:

> "x must be numeric"

I've tried rewriting the code, but can't get it to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit:

I added some data:

```
elderly female  white   stroke
1   1   1   0
0   0   1   0
0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0
0   1   1   0
0   0   1   0
0   1   0   0
1   0   1   0
0   0   1   0
0   1   1   0
```

EDIT AGAIN: solution found

```
fillmatrix = function(data,features) {
    OR.matrix = matrix(nrow=length(features),ncol=length(features))
    for (i in 3:length(features)) {
        for (d in 3:length(features)) {
            or = oddsratio(data[,i],data[,d])
            OR.matrix[i,d] = or
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which function gives the error? And what package is `odds.ratio` from? Does your `oddsratio()` function work if you call it manually outside of the `for` loop with 2 of these features? How far does your loop get? Since you don't use `features` inside your `loop` function, it seems like it shouldn't be an argument (but maybe `all` should be an argument?). It also seems strange that `loop` doesn't store any results or return anything other than the last result. Have you tried running the for loop outside of the `loop` function?

Comment: Hi Gregor, odds.ratio is from questionr. The oddsratio() function works fine if I manually enter the two features that I want to compare without the loop. The loop crashes once it gets to oddsratio(). I'm planning to take the results from the loop and feed them into a matrix, but haven't gotten that far yet. I'd like to scale to datasets with hundreds of features, so I'm focusing on getting this part correct first.

Comment: I'd recommend adding a `print(i)` statement inside your loop so you can see how far it gets. If the last `i` that works is, say, 21, then you can look at `all[, 21]`, try running `oddsratio()` on that and hopefully figure out what's going on. If you need more help than that, you should share a little sample data so your question is reproducible.

Comment: Thanks Gregor. I've tried the print() and oddsratio() doesn't work at all within the loop. I edited the post with some data.

Comment: Since it's clear that data types matter here, can you use `dput()` to share your data? That way all the column classes and everything will be preserved. Just `dput(your_sample_data)` and paste the result into the question.

Comment: Hi Gregor - I figured out a solution. Thanks for your help! Sorry that I didn't provide a clear question.